# Angular view changes is too slow

Tags: angular

I have a very simple angular app.
below is the snippet of html file

```
  <div>{{some_string}}</div>
```

below is the ts file

```
some_string!: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
   //an api call is made to get value of the variable some_string
   on_api_call.subscribe(
        next: (data: any) => {
          this.some_string = data
          console.log(this.some_string)
        },
        error: (data: any) => {
        }
   )
}
```

Expected behavior below
When I load the component in the browser.

1. The api call is made
2. The api response is received under a second and the value is assigned to **some_string** variable.
3. The value is printed in the browser console -> **console.log(this.some_string)**

> 4. The **some_string** value should display in the browser ->`<div>{{some_string}}</div>**`

Here is where I am noticing this strange behavior.
The **some_string** value is not rendered in the browser immediately, rather it takes over 10 seconds to reflect.

This code was working just fine yesterday.

1. I see no compilation errors
2. I do not see this issue in the development env, **some_string** value is rendered in the browser immediately.
3. This issue is happening only in production.

Adding timelines to each event for better understanding (hh:mm:ss).

1. Browser page refresh - 00:00:00
2. Outgoing API call - 00:00:01
3. API response received - 00:00:02
4. value printed in browser console -> **console.log(this.some_string)** - 00:00:02
5. new value reflected in div tag -> 00:00.15

Notice how there is over 10 seconds gap in step 4 and 5. Ideally they should happen in micro seconds.

Comment: Seems like an I/O timing/responsiveness issue somewhere. Look in the browser's debug console and then view the network tab. You can see the calls as they happen including timing, duration, concurrent-ness, etc. You should be able to use that to figure out what call is blocking for 10 seconds on production. You can then investigate further into why.

Comment: Hey Igor, As mentioned, below line is printed in the browser console  "console.log(this.some_string)", which means the api call was perfectly alright and the result is received, however they is over 10 seconds delay between "the value printer in browser console" and "value show in the div".

Comment: There is likely something else happening that is taking 10 seconds to process but the best start would be to look at the network calls being made. Likely you will see something that is taking 10 seconds to complete. If you want to ignore that advise about checking your network calls that is OK but there is not much else for anyone else reading this question to go on.

Comment: Have you tried using an Async Pipe? Not sure it would fix the issue, but worth a shot. The fact it is only happening in production makes me think this issue has more to do with server and IO configuration than Angular itself.